# How to get only the id value corresponding to the clicked value in JQuery

Tags: jquery

This is my php code that I can click folder That folder name is One, Two, Three

```
echo '<div class="tile folder" id ="One"><i class="mdi mdi-folder"></i><p>One</p></div>';
echo '<div class="tile folder" id = "Two"><i class="mdi mdi-folder"></i><p>Two</p></div>';
echo '<div class="tile folder" id = "Three"><i class="mdi mdi-folder"></i><p>Three</p></div>';
```

And This is my JQuery Code

```
  $('.folder').on( "click", function() {
      var id = $('.tile').attr('id');
      console.log(id);
```

If I click folders, The log always says One.
I want to make if I click One folder it says One, if I click Two folder, it says Two. How to edit it?

Comment: Inside the click event handler, if you use `function()` then `this` is the element clicked.  Use `this.id` to get the id.

Answer (score 1):

Just one correction.

```
$('.folder').on( "click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: Just `this.id` no need for `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for the first `.tile` again. You will need to use `$(this)` to get the correct folder.

```
 $('.folder').on( "click", function() {
      var what = '하하';
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      console.log(id);
 });
```

Comment: Just `this.id` no need for `$(this)`